# This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-reports

This query runs an item ledger. When i try to sum Returns field on access report by using =SUM([Returns]) i.e Return is text box on access report. it shows following error when report is run. 
**

> This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be
>   evaluated. For example, a numeric expression may contain too many
>   complicated elements. Try simplifying the expression by assigning
>   parts of the expression to variables.

**

```
SELECT ITEM, [Transaction Date], ID, Reciept, Issued, Returns, Remarks, Manual
FROM 
 (SELECT t.item AS ITEM, irh.reciept_date AS [Transaction Date], ird.inv_id AS ID, ird.inv_qyt AS Reciept, Null AS Issued, NULL AS Returns, ird.remarks AS Remarks, ird.inv_manual_number AS Manual
FROM inventory_reciepts_header AS irh, inventory_reciepts_detail AS ird, inventory AS t
WHERE 
ird.inv_id=t.id 
AND ird.reciept_header_id=irh.id
UNION ALL

 SELECT t.item AS ITEM, iih.issue_date As  [Transaction Date], iid.inventory_id AS ID,NULL AS Reciept, iid.inventory_qyt AS Issued, NULL AS Returns, iid.remarks AS Remarks,Null AS Manual 
FROM inventory_issue_header AS iih, inventory_issue_detail AS iid,inventory 
AS t  WHERE  iid.inventory_id=t.id
    AND 
    iid.issue_header_id=iih.id

UNION ALL    
 SELECT t.item AS ITEM, iirh.return_date As  [Transaction Date], iir.item_id AS ID, Null AS Reciept, NULL AS Issued,iir.qyt AS Returns, iir.reasons AS Remarks,Null AS Manual 
FROM inventory_return_header AS iirh, inventory_return_detail AS iir, inventory AS t
WHERE      
iir.item_id=t.id
AND 
iir.return_header_id=iirh.id
 ) AS [ITEM Ledger]
WHERE ID=[Forms]![Reports Window]![cmb_ar]
and
[Transaction Date] between [Forms]![Reports Window]![ar_frm_dt] And [Forms]![Reports Window]![ar_to_dt];
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the *data type* of the parameters in the header:

```
PARAMETERS 
    [Forms]![Reports Window]![cmb_ar] Long,
    [Forms]![Reports Window]![ar_frm_dt] DateTime,
    [Forms]![Reports Window]![ar_to_dt] DateTime;
SELECT 
    ITEM, [Transaction Date], ID, Reciept, Issued, Returns, Remarks, Manual
FROM
<snip>
```

**Addendum**

*Sum* probably fails because the field is returned as text because of the *Null* values in the first query.

A solution is to make the query expect the field value to be a number. That can be accomplished with the expression:

```
IIf(False, 0, Null)
```

The condition to check, *False*, will never be True, thus the expression will always return Null, but – nevertheless – the query evaluates both output options and decides this to be *numeric*.

Insert the expression, and the query will read:

```
SELECT 
    t.item AS ITEM, 
    irh.reciept_date AS [Transaction Date], 
    ird.inv_id AS ID, 
    ird.inv_qyt AS Reciept, 
    IIf(False, 0, Null) AS Issued, 
    IIf(False, 0, Null) AS Returns, 
    ird.remarks AS Remarks, 
    ird.inv_manual_number AS Manual
FROM 
    inventory_reciepts_header AS irh, 
    inventory_reciepts_detail AS ird, 
    inventory AS t
<snip>
```

Comment: Dear Gustav, This report runs successfully without =SUM([Returns]) . on applying =SUM([Returns]) in report  throws error.

Comment: You may succeed with `=Sum(Val([Returns]))` - or see edited answer.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. Solved by using =SUM(Nz([Returns])).